DefaultKeyBinding.dic no longer remaps ctl+arrow windows shortcuts after MacOS update
On my macbook I use DefaultKeyBinding.dict to remap about 12 keys to what they would be in Windows.
However, after my update to MacOS Ventura, the remappings for moveWordLeft and moveWordRight stopped working.  I read somewhere that DefaultKeyBinding.dict now refers to those functions as moveWordForward and moveWordBackward, so I updated accordingly but it still doesnt work. All other keys still work fine. Here is what I have tried
"^\UF702" = moveWordLeft:;
"^\UF703" = moveWordRight:;

which was updated to
 "@\UF702" = moveWordBackward:;
 "^\UF703" = moveWordForward:;

How can I get this to work again?

Is the @ in "@\UF702" = moveWordBackward:; a typo?

No, in googleing this I saw variations on how to specify the characters and @ seems to have same effect as ^

Just a shot in the dark, but the Apple Developer Documentation for DefaultKeyBinding.dict places double quotes around the command as well as the key code, like this:
 "^\UF702" = "moveWordBackward:";
 "^\UF703" = "moveWordForward:";


Tried that, with both moveWordBackward and moveWordLeft, but still doesnt work. And the other keys that do work don't have quotes there anyway
